# Is there polish translation for dropzone.js?

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

Is there a polish translation for dropzone.js (https://www.dropzonejs.com)?

---

Istnieje polskie tłumaczenie do skryptu dropzone.js?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```js
      /**
       * The text used before any files are dropped.
       */
      dictDefaultMessage: "Kliknij i wybierz pliki lub przeciągnij i upuść tutaj",

      /**
       * The text that replaces the default message text it the browser is not supported.
       */
      dictFallbackMessage: "Twoja przeglądarka nie wspiera przeciągania i upuszczania plików.",

      /**
       * The text that will be added before the fallback form.
       * If you provide a  fallback element yourself, or if this option is `null` this will
       * be ignored.
       */
      dictFallbackText: "Użyj poniższego formularza by wgrać pliki.",

      /**
       * If the filesize is too big.
       * `{{filesize}}` and `{{maxFilesize}}` will be replaced with the respective configuration values.
       */
      dictFileTooBig: "Plik jest zbyt duży ({{filesize}}MiB). Maksymalny rozmiar pliku: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",

      /**
       * If the file doesn't match the file type.
       */
      dictInvalidFileType: "Nie możesz wgrać plików tego typu.",

      /**
       * If the server response was invalid.
       * `{{statusCode}}` will be replaced with the servers status code.
       */
      dictResponseError: "Kod odpowiedzi serwera: {{statusCode}}.",

      /**
       * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used for the cancel upload link.
       */
      dictCancelUpload: "Przerwij wgrywanie",

      /**
       * The text that is displayed if an upload was manually canceled
       */
      dictUploadCanceled: "Wgrywanie przerwane.",

      /**
       * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used for confirmation when cancelling upload.
       */
      dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "Jesteś pewien, że chcesz przerwać wgrywanie?",

      /**
       * If `addRemoveLinks` is true, the text to be used to remove a file.
       */
      dictRemoveFile: "Usuń plik",

      /**
       * If this is not null, then the user will be prompted before removing a file.
       */
      dictRemoveFileConfirmation: null,

      /**
       * Displayed if `maxFiles` is st and exceeded.
       * The string `{{maxFiles}}` will be replaced by the configuration value.
       */
      dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Nie możesz wgrać więcej plików.",
```